# Getting "Value cannot be null" with HTML Helper

Tags: razor, null

I am getting a "Value cannot be null" error from the code below:

```
@Html.Label(material.ExtendedGroup)
```

`ExtendedGroup` is indeed `null`, but I would like to know how handle this with Razor's HTML helper -- something equivalent to `Isnull(material.ExtendedGroup,"",material.ExtendedGroup)` that we do in MS SQL. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) would do the trick:

```
@Html.Label(material.ExtendedGroup ?? "default value")
```